# Node Express -- using more than one request parameter breaks the CSS styling of the HTML file my get handler sends

Tags: express, parameters, request

EDIT: I found the problem -- my style sheet was relatively linked when it should have been an absolute link.

The express get handler in question is intended to be called when someone clicks a generated link -- it works fine, but then I tried to add a second request parameter and now the rendered page doesn't seem to have any CSS styling and is just keeps loading.

First, I use just the `:creator` request parameter. Here's the code:

```
  //djApp.get('/:creator/:hash', function (req, res) {
  djApp.get('/:creator/', function (req, res) {
    var path = req.params.creator.toLowerCase();
    for(booth in boothList) {
      if (path == boothList[booth].creator.toLowerCase()) {
        res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', setTimeout(function () {
          for (c in clients) {
            if (clients[c].url && clients[c].url == path) {
              clients[c].socket.emit('redirectUser', {'booth': boothList[booth]});
            }
          }
        }, 500));
        /*var hash = req.params.hash;
        if (hashes.indexOf(hash) > -1) {
          console.log("path is "+path+"\nhash is "+hash+"\nhashIndex is "+hashes.indexOf(hash));
          hashes.splice(hashes.indexOf(hash), 1);
          res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', setTimeout(function () {
            for (c in clients) {
              if (clients[c].url && clients[c].url == path) {
                clients[c].socket.emit('redirectUser', {'booth': boothList[booth]});
              }
            }
          }, 500));
        }*/
      }
    }
  });
});

djApp.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

This is the generated URL that the handler is using:

```
http://localhost:3001/Aweeeezy
```

Here is a screenshot demonstrating that the HTML is sent and properly links the CSS and JS as expected:[image]

Next I comment out the app.get line with the single request parameter and the logic block that sends the html file and then uncomment the app.get line with two request parameters and an identical logic block for sending the html file, only it sits inside a if condition related to the additional request parameter. Here's the code:

```
  //djApp.get('/:creator/', function (req, res) {
  djApp.get('/:creator/:hash', function (req, res) {
    var path = req.params.creator.toLowerCase();
    for(booth in boothList) {
      if (path == boothList[booth].creator.toLowerCase()) {
        var hash = req.params.hash;
        if (hashes.indexOf(hash) > -1) {
          console.log("path is "+path+"\nhash is "+hash+"\nhashIndex is "+hashes.indexOf(hash));
          hashes.splice(hashes.indexOf(hash), 1);
          res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', setTimeout(function () {
            for (c in clients) {
              if (clients[c].url && clients[c].url == path) {
                clients[c].socket.emit('redirectUser', {'booth': boothList[booth]});
              }
            }
          }, 500));
          /*res.sendFile(__dirname+'/public/index.html', setTimeout(function () {
            for (c in clients) {
              if (clients[c].url && clients[c].url == path) {
                clients[c].socket.emit('redirectUser', {'booth': boothList[booth]});
              }
            }
          }, 500));*/
        }
      }
    }
  });
});

djApp.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```

This is the generated URL that the handler is using:

```
http://localhost:3001/Aweeeezy/a35969699812c71ef8fde58cafebe644dd18ed7b
```

Output is:

```
path is aweeeezy
hash is a35969699812c71ef8fde58cafebe644dd18ed7b
hashIndex is 0
```

So you can see that everything works as expected inside the handler -- at least up to the code that is identical to the working case, but my browser now renders the page like this: [image]

What it really comes down to is the difference from `/:creator` to `/:creator/:hash` in the request handler URL -- but every example I see for use of multiple parameters does what I'm trying to do.

What's going on?!

Comment: Did you find any solution. Same thing happening to me?@aweeeezy

Answer (score 0):

Change the link to the style sheet to be an absolute link.